# my gamescene shows black screen when i added autoparallax code in gamescene in andengine

Tags: java, android, andengine

i added autoparallax code to the gamescene, my game works,but background shows blackscreen, please help me, thank you in advance.
 in resourcemanager.java

private void loadGameGraphics()
    {

```
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/game/");
     mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(activity.getTextureManager(), 1024, 1024,TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
     mParallaxLayerFront = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset( mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture, activity, "parallax_background_layer_front.png", 0, 0);
     mParallaxLayerBack = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(  mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture, activity, "parallax_background_layer_back.png", 0, 188);
     mParallaxLayerMid = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset( mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture, activity, "parallax_background_layer_mid.png", 0, 669);
     }
```

in gamescene.java

private Scene createBackground()
    {

```
            resourcesManager.mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture.load();
    final Scene scene = new Scene();
    final AutoParallaxBackground autoParallaxBackground = new AutoParallaxBackground(0, 0, 0, 5);

    int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
    autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(0.0f, new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - resourcesManager.mParallaxLayerBack.getHeight(), resourcesManager.mParallaxLayerBack,vbom)));
    autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-5.0f, new Sprite(0, 80,  resourcesManager.mParallaxLayerMid, vbom)));
    autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-10.0f, new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - resourcesManager.mParallaxLayerFront.getHeight(),  resourcesManager.mParallaxLayerFront, vbom)));
    scene.setBackground(autoParallaxBackground);
 return scene; 

}
```

STACKTRACE

02-19 05:01:55.710: W/AndEngine(1083): The OffsetCenterXposition of a ParallaxEntity is expected to be 0.
02-19 05:01:55.710: W/AndEngine(1083): The OffsetCenterXposition of a ParallaxEntity is expected to be 0.
02-19 05:01:55.710: W/AndEngine(1083): The OffsetCenterXposition of a ParallaxEntity is expected to be 0.

Comment: Change 1024,1024 to 2048,2048.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i changed to 2048, but again it shows black screen, i added logcat.

Comment: what are the pixel dimensions of your 3 background images?

Comment: back.png-640*480,  front.png-640*187,  mid.png-640*85

Comment: mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture.load(); add this line if you did not added

Comment: i added that line, i don't know whether its on correct position.

Comment: please can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Move this line

```
resourcesManager.mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture.load();
```

from createBackground() to loadGameGraphics().

Comment: Welcome! :) If you would like to, please accept my answer as well. Thank you!